# Where can I educate myself about palm trees?

Tags: plant-recommendations, palm

I'm looking for a palm tree to provide a back drop to a swimming pool. I think I want a medium sized palm but I know nothing about them and need to educate myself. Where can I learn about the different palms that are available and what would be most suitable for my needs.

I've already tried going to local nurseries but they only seem to be interested in advising me on palms that they have in stock and I worry that I'm not getting objective advice.

Comment: You might get a better response if you modify your question to "Which palm tree species will grow to x feet, +(other characteristics)?"

Comment: Well you should probably keep trying local nurseries, or maybe a local club... Then go back and buy a canary island date palm, or sago palm (cycad)... at least half kidding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may sound old fashioned, but I'd get myself a very good palm book and then make my choice. Several recommendations for the most useful are made on this site : www.florida-palm-trees.com/palm-tree-books or else just Google 'books on palm trees'. I'd probably choose 'All About Palms' because its not too expensive.